# Ubuntu taskbar 12.04

Tags: 12.04

In Ubuntu 10.04, I had the taskbar (Applications, Places and System).  I could easily navigate to anything...

Now in Ubuntu 12.04, I no longer have the taskbar. yes, I have the search feature, but I really do not like that.

How do I get it back?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic-desktop

Answer (score 0):

Install gnome classic (also known as gnome flashback) desktop environment. Open the terminal and enter
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-flashback. Logout and select the gnome classic environment from the login screen.